# Extend array types using where clause in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, swift-extensions

I'd like to use the Accelerate framework to extend [Float] and [Double] but each of these requires a different implementation.

I tried the obvious:

```
extension Array<Float> {
}
```

and get this error:

> "Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialised generic
>   type 'Array' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause"

Is it posible to extend generic types in Swift 2 in this way?

I've got the code working as expected now.  Here's an example showing a summation using the Accelerate framework.

```
extension _ArrayType where Generator.Element == Float {

    func quickSum() -> Float {
        var result: Float = 0
        if var x = self as? [Float] {
            vDSP_sve(&x, 1, &result, vDSP_Length(x.count))
        }
        return result
    }
}

extension _ArrayType where Generator.Element == Double {

    func quickSum() -> Double {
        var result: Double = 0
        if var x = self as? [Double] {
            vDSP_sveD(&x, 1, &result, vDSP_Length(x.count))
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

If you want to extend only array with specific type. You should extend _ArrayType protocol.

```
extension _ArrayType where Generator.Element == Int {

   func doSomething() {
       ... 
   }
}
```

If you extend `Array` you can only make sure your element is conformed some protocol else. i.e:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {

   func doSomething() {
       ... 
   }
}
```

**Updated:
With Swift 3.1** https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

```
extension Array where Element == Int {

   func doSomething() {
       ... 
   }
}
```

Comment: This really helped me for a slightly different problem. I was overriding Array and using contains(element) which did not work until I constrained the extension to Element : Equatable. To see what the different constraints are (and what methods they affect) see also SequenceType: http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/SequenceType/

Comment: I think you should use `SequenceType` instead of `_ArrayType`

Comment: The answer works perfectly with Swift 2.2, but _ArrayType has disappeared in Swift 3. How should we do it now?

Comment: @Maiaux See my answer below.

Comment: In swift 3.1, `extension Array where Element == Int` gives error **error: same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Element' non-generic
extension Array where Element == Int**, give me suggestion

Comment: @BenLu Your answer works but now I don't have access to subscripts for the collection. For instance, if I write self[0] I get a "Cannot subscript a value of type Self with an index of type Int" error

Answer (score 29):

Swift 3 to the rescue!!

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Int {
    // `Collection` can be `Sequence`, etc
}
```

Comment: This works, but now I don't have access to subscripts for the collection. For instance, if I write `self[0]` I get a "Cannot subscript a value of type Self with an index of type Int" error

Comment: @Maiaux because `subscript` is not a function and does not support generics, so I guess this doesn't work too well.

Comment: Any other swift 3 solution that supports subscripts?

Answer (score 16):

How about

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == Double {

}
```

Or If you want a little bit more:

```
protocol ArithmeticType {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Double : ArithmeticType {}
extension Float : ArithmeticType {}

extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : protocol<FloatLiteralConvertible, ArithmeticType> {
    var sum : Generator.Element {
        return reduce(0.0, combine: +)
    }

    var product : Generator.Element {
        return reduce(1.0, combine: *)
    }
}


stride(from: 1.0, through: 10.0, by: 1.0).sum   // 55
[1.5, 2.0, 3.5, 4.0, 5.5].product               // 231
```

Works with `Double` and `Float` or any other type that you conform to the protocols `ArithmeticType` and `FloatLiteralConvertible`. If you need to access specific indices of your array, change `SequenceType` to `CollectionType` as you cannot do this with a sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3 on Xcode 8.2

Just need to extend Sequence protocol and provide a where statement.

```
let someString = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8"

extension String {        
  func toArrayOfElements() -> [String] {
    return self.components(separatedBy: ", ")
  }        
}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == String {        
  func toInt() -> [Int] {            
    return self.map {
      Int($0)!
    }
  }        
}

let arrayOfStrings = someString.toArrayOfElements()    
print(arrayOfStrings)

let arrayOfInts = arrayOfStrings.toInt()    
print(arrayOfInts)
```

Answer (score 4):

So I didn't read the question properly.  `FloatingPointType` is an existing protocol that is implemented by Double, Float and CGFloat, so

Yes.  I did it only yesterday to add a function to SequenceType where the elements had to be `Equatable`.  This is a modification to restrict the elements to `Float`

You need to use a where clause.  This is my function below.

```
public extension SequenceType where Self.Generator.Element: FloatingPointType
{
    public func splitAt(separator: Generator.Element) -> [[Generator.Element]]
    {
        var ret: [[Generator.Element]] = []
        var thisPart: [Generator.Element] = []

        for element in self
        {
            if element == separator
            {
                ret.append(thisPart)
                thisPart = []
            }
            else
            {
                thisPart.append(element)
            }
        }
        ret.append(thisPart)
        return ret
    }
}

[Float(1), Float(2), Float(3), Float(4)].splitAt(Float(2))
// returns [[1],[3, 4]]
[Double(1), Double(2), Double(3), Double(4)].splitAt(Double(3))
// returns [[1, 2],[4]]
```

NB I couldn't make this work for an array but SequenceType is more general anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to extend a specific `Array` you have to use a protocol for each type:

```
protocol DoubleValue {
    var value: Double { get }
}
extension Double: DoubleValue {
    var value: Double { return self }
}
extension Array where Element: DoubleValue {
    // use the value property
}

// the same for Float
protocol FloatValue {
    var value: Float { get }
}

extension Float: FloatValue {
    var value: Float { return self }
}
extension Array where Element: FloatValue {
    // use the value property
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I'm using `Swift 5`.

```
extension Array where Iterator.Element == Float {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what it worked for me using `Swift 5`:

```swift
extension Array where ArrayLiteralElement == Float {

}
```