# extend generic Array<T> to adopt protocol

Tags: swift, generics

Let's say I've defined such a protocol:

```
protocol EuclideanPoint {
    func distance(other: Self) -> Double
    func dimension() -> UInt
}
```

Now I'd like to extend `[Float]` and `[Double]` to adopt that protocol.

But the following code:

```
extension [Float]: EuclideanPoint {
    func distance(other: [Float]) {
        return Double(zip(self, other).map{a, b in pow(a-b,2)}.reduce(0, combine: +))
    }
    func dimension() {
        return UInt(self.count)
    }
}
```

is invalid because of the error

> error: constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic type 'Array' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause

I found similar questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842337/how-can-i-make-a-extension-for-array-of-specific-type-in-swift)), but the suggested solution is to use `extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == S { ... }`, but in this context it leads to the error:

> error: protocol 'CollectionType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Is there any solution to this?

EDIT:

using the proposed solution:

```
protocol DoubleConvertibleType {
    var doubleValue: Double { get }
}

extension Double : DoubleConvertibleType { var doubleValue: Double { return self         } }
extension Float  : DoubleConvertibleType { var doubleValue: Double { return Double(self) } }
extension CGFloat: DoubleConvertibleType { var doubleValue: Double { return Double(self) } }

extension Array where Element : DoubleConvertibleType {
    func distance(other: Array) -> Double {
        return Double(zip(self, other).map{ pow($0.0.doubleValue - $0.1.doubleValue, 2) }.reduce(0, combine: +))
    }

    func dimension() -> UInt {
        return UInt(self.count)
    }
}
```

gives `[Double]` and `[Float]` the `.distance()` and `.dimension()` methods. Yet `[Double]` or `[Float]` cannot be used in place of something that is required to conform to the EuclideanPoint protocol, producing the error:

> error: type '[Double]' does not conform to protocol 'EuclideanPoint'

Comment: you should take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28288619/2303865

Comment: In Swift 4 (coming this fall) you can do `extension Array: EuclideanPoint where Element: DoubleConvertibleType {}`. This is currently not possible. (See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED

---

The following solution is somewhat generic, conforms to protocol `EuclidianPoint`, and is based upon two assumptions:

- That we're allowed to include a generic type constraint for your blueprint for method `distance` in your `EuclideanPoint` protocol, and that, instead of argument type being `Self`, we'll use a generic (`[T]`). We will, however, ascertain (at compile time) that `[T]` is of the same type as `Self` (and here, `Self` of `[Double]`, `[Float]` or `[Int]` type), and *ascertain that [T] conforms to the protocol `EuclidianPoint`*.
- That you're ok that we leave functional programming techniques such as `.map` and `.reduce` out of this specific application, and focus only on attaining a *"generic array adopted to euclidian protocol"*. These `.map`, `.reduce` etc feats in Swift are indeed neat and useful, but are in many applications just wrappers for behind-the-hood for-loops, so you won't lose any performance over doing things in a manual imperative style. In fact, `.reduce` is known to perform quite non-optional due to repeated array-copy-assignments while reducing the array (I won't go into this more here...). Anyway, perhaps you can make use of my example and tweak it back to something more functional-paradigmy.

---

We begin by a custom type protocol, `MyTypes`, that will act as an interface for which types we want to include in our generic. We also add the slightly updated `EuiclidianPoint` protocol, where we use protocol `MyTypes` as a type restraint to the generic `T` used in the `distance (...)` function blue-print.

```
/* Used as type constraint for Generator.Element */
protocol MyTypes {
    func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func +=(inout lhs: Self, rhs: Self)
}

extension Int : MyTypes { }
extension Double : MyTypes { }
extension Float : MyTypes { }
    /* Extend with the types you wish to be covered by the generic ... */

/* Used as extension to Array : blueprints for extension method
to Array where Generator.Element are constrainted to MyTypes */
protocol EuclideanPoint {
    func distance<T: MyTypes> (other: [T]) -> Double?
    func dimension() -> UInt
}
```

Note that I've changed the `Double` return of `distance` to an optional; you may handle this as you will, but in case the lengths of `self` and `other` arrays differ, or types `Self` and `[T]` differ, there will be some need of showing non-conformance -- I'll use `nil` for this here.

We can now implement implement our extension of `Array` by the `EuclidianPoint` protocol:

```
/* Array extension by EuclideanPoint protocol */
extension Array : EuclideanPoint {

    func distance<T: MyTypes> (other: [T]) -> Double? {
        /* [T] is Self? proceed, otherwise return nil */
        if let a = self.first {
            if a is T && self.count == other.count {
                var mySum: Double = 0.0
                for (i, sElement) in self.enumerate() {
                    mySum += pow(((sElement as! T) - other[i]) as! Double, 2)
                }
                return sqrt(mySum)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func dimension() -> UInt {
        return UInt(self.count)
    }
}
```

Note that in the inner if clause of the `distance` function we use an explicit down cast to `T`, but since we've asserted that elements of `Self` are of type `T`, this is ok.

Anyway, with this, we're done, and we can test our "generic" array extensions, which we note now also conforms to your protocol `EuclidianPoint`.

```
/* Tests and Examples */
let arr1d : [Double] = [3.0, 4.0, 0.0]
let arr2d : [Double] = [-3.0, -4.0, 0.0]
let arr3d : [Double] = [-3.0, -4.0]

let arr1f : [Float] = [-3.0, -4.0, 0.0]

let arr1i = [1, 2, 3]

let _a = arr1d.dimension() // 3, OK
let _b = arr1d.distance(arr2d) // 10, OK (A->B dist)
let _c = arr1d.distance(arr1f) // nil (Incomp. types)
let _d = arr1d.distance(arr3d) // nil (Incomp. sizes)
let _e = arr1i.distance(arr1d) // nil (Incomp. types)

    /* for use in function calls: generic array parameters constrained to
       those that conform to protocol 'EuclidianPoint', as requested     */
func bar<T: MyTypes, U: protocol<EuclideanPoint, _ArrayType> where U.Generator.Element == T> (arr1: U, _ arr2: U) -> Double? {

    // ...

    return arr1.distance(Array(arr2))
        /* We'll need to explicitly tell the distance function
           here that we're sending an array, by initializing an 
           array using the Array(..) initializer                */
}
let myDist = bar(arr1d, arr2d) // 10, OK
```

Ok!

---

A note still remaining from my first answer:

Extension of generic type Array to protocol was actually just recently asked here:

- [Extending typed array by conforming to a protocol in Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467606/extending-typed-array-by-conforming-to-a-protocol-in-swift-2/34468382#34468382)

The consensus is the you *cannot do a generic extension of array to a protocol* in the "neat swifty" way that you possible expect. There are however workarounds to mimic such a behaviour, one being the one I've used above. If you are interested in another method, I suggest you look into this thread.

Comment: You can't it will throw an errorr = type 'Element' constrained to non-protocol type 'Double'

Comment: You can use extension Array where Element: FloatingPointType or a custom protocol

Comment: @LeoDabus Note that `FloatingPointType`, for some reason, does not include the basic binary operators, so you'll need to add blueprints to these in an additional protocol (or likewise)

Comment: you can also add a doubleValue property

Comment: @LeoDabus Ah, I didn't know that, thanks! Regarding your first answer: yes, I was to quick on this one, wrote on my iPad, now on Laptop :) will fix

Comment: your change to the EuclideanPoint protocol makes impossible to write functions that work with the protocol only, i.e. `func f(p1: EuclideanPoint, p2: EuclideanPoint)` because you cannot do `p1.distance(p2)` (I'm excluding downcasts and other ugly hacks when I say impossible :D)

Comment: @mescalinum I assume you mean if you want to use only the protocol `EuclideanPoint` as a type constraint (e.g. `func f<T: EuclideanPoint>(p1: T, p2: T) { let myDist = p1.distance(p2) ... }`). (Your example `func f(p1: EuclideanPoint, p2: EuclideanPoint)` won't work with the original `EuclideanPoint` protocol either; `EuclideanPoint` is a protocol, not a type). Anyway, I think you are right that it is, for this solution/case, difficult to add such type constraints that *explicitly* tells us functions parameters conform to type (here) `EuclidianPoint`).  _<... next comment>_

Comment: ... You can, however, get this behaviour _implictly_: you can create a type constraint protocol (say, `SomeType`) which is specifically used *only* as type constraint in the blueprint methods for `EuclidianPoint`. You can then add this type constraint to your functions, e.g., `func f<T: SomeType>(p1: [T], p2: [T]) { let myDist = p1.distance(p2) ... }`: this will add a type constraint on the `Generator.Element` type (`T` here) in your functions array parameters, which _implicitly_ assures that the arrays sent as parameters are of type `EuclidianPoint`.

Comment: @mescalinum I've now re-invented the answer and added a fix so that you can constrain array parameter generics in functions to specifically use `EuclidianPoint` as a type constraint. So, the change in `EuclidianPoint` does indeed *not* make it impossible to work with the protocol, and we don't have to make use of ugly hacks :) (and not, per se, downcasts, however, array initialization, `p1.distance(Array(p2))`)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `SequenceType` instead of `Array`

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == Float {
//
}
```

Comment: `SequenceType` has no count property. A similar property is needed by `EuclideanPoint` protocol

Comment: @fferri @Adam : `(self as! [Float]).count`  self now has count

Answer (score 1):

*Foreword*: As @difri correctly mentions in the comment we can not yet create an extension conforming to a protocol when using generic constrains at the same time. There are already a couple of radars open - searching for *"extension of type with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause"* will yield a couple of them.

*Actual Answer*: Building on [@LeoDabus awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28288619/2442804) and my experimenting I came up with the following:

```
protocol DoubleConvertibleType {
    var doubleValue: Double { get }
}

extension Double : DoubleConvertibleType { var doubleValue: Double { return self         } }
extension Float  : DoubleConvertibleType { var doubleValue: Double { return Double(self) } }
extension CGFloat: DoubleConvertibleType { var doubleValue: Double { return Double(self) } }

extension Array where Element : DoubleConvertibleType {
    func distance(other: Array) -> Double {
        return Double(zip(self, other).map{ pow($0.0.doubleValue - $0.1.doubleValue, 2) }.reduce(0, combine: +))
    }

    func dimension() -> UInt {
        return UInt(self.count)
    }
}
```

Testing it with

```
let arr1 = [1.5, 2, 3]
let arr2 = [5.5, 2, 3]
let arrD = arr1.distance(arr2)
```

Somewhat correctly prints

> 16

To get the correct answer (at least what I would suspect) you have to wrap the `distance` into `sqrt`:

```
return sqrt(Double(zip(self, other).map{ pow($0.0.doubleValue - $0.1.doubleValue,2) }.reduce(0, combine: +)))
```

Which then correctly prints

> 4

Comment: This solves the problem described in the details of the question (and does so neatly!), but I think it's worth mentioning that it does not solve the problem asked in the question title: _we cannot (in neat swifty way) extend a generic type to a protocol_. Note that the solution above removes protocol `EuclideanPoint` of the equation. Good answer, plus1, but just so people don't click in here and think this solves the much trickier problem "generic Array<T> conformance to protocol"!

Comment: @mescalinum I was fiddling around with it for quite some time now trying to avoid creating a special protocol for that purpose but seems that is unavoidable.

Comment: @dfri you are absolutely right, completely forget about the actual protocol we were trying to conform to :D hmmm

Comment: I think this probably does it for the question poster (as he came up with the same answer), and should be accepted. But if possible, please add into your answer that it does just this: solves the specific problem but not the generic array to protocol trickster! Then, if anyone wanna go all out and really attack the latter, they should probably refer to the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467606/extending-typed-array-by-conforming-to-a-protocol-in-swift-2/34468382#34468382

Comment: @dfri just did that because it is an absolutely valid point - thanks.

Comment: @dfri indeed this does *not* solve the problem. trying to use the (extended) `[Double]` type where `EuclideanPoint` is required, produces the error: error: type '[Double]' does not conform to protocol 'EuclideanPoint'

Comment: @luk2302 Note that `FloatingPointType` is actually an existing fundamental swift protocol (http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/FloatingPointType/) that we overwrite here at a local scope here (contains initialiser blueprints and so on; adopted by `Double`, `Float` and `CGFloat`), so perhaps another name should be used for this protocol, e.g. `MyFloatingPointProtocol`.