# Why can't I call function that was defaulted through protocol extension?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols, swift-extensions, swift2

I have extended the following protocol with a default parameter.

```
protocol XDelegate {
    func close(response: Bool, status: Status)
}

extension XDelegate{
    func close(response: Bool, status: Status = .UNDEFINED){}
}
```

whenever I call `delegate.close(true)` it won't EVER call the function on the class that adopted this protocol.

I MUST do `delegate.close(true, status: .UNDEFINED)` so it would call the function.

Is this the expected behavior?

I'm using Swift 2.3

**EDIT:** See the duplicate link and also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40855083/5175709) and the **comments** below it.

Comment: This looks quite similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634816/implementing-a-function-with-a-default-parameter-defined-in-a-protocol – duplicate?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601931/is-it-possible-to-satisfy-swift-protocol-and-add-defaulted-arguments

Comment: Your default parameter version in the extension should call the other one in its implementation

Comment: Most probably unrelated to the issue, but why use Swift 2.3 when Swift 4 is being released soon and Swift 3 has been out for quite a while now?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Long story short. Not my decision!