# Is this a bug in Xcode or a practice should be avoid by programmer?

Tags: swift, xcode, protocol-extension

In the first place, I looked for a way to simplify coding by providing default argument values for protocol functions. I took the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601931/is-it-possible-to-satisfy-swift-protocol-and-add-defaulted-arguments) and then found some fatal subsequence it may bring:

```
protocol Foo {
    func foo(_ a: Int)
}

extension Foo {
    func foo(_ a: Int = 4) {
        foo(a)
    }
}

struct FooImpl: Foo {
    // empty implementation
}

FooImpl().foo() // will go recursively forever and finally reach the stack limit
```

I also found that this code would fail to compile in [IBM Swift Sandbox](https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl) thus supposing xcode compiler might be to blame.

Comment: Is the comment the compiler error you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks to be valid Swift code that the compiler should accept and execute.  That it contains a fatal infinite recursion is a logic error on the part of the programmer.

I don't see anything in the IBM Swift Sandbox to indicate that it handles the code any better, or differently, than Xcode.

Comment: IBM Sandbox says "The Swift compiler reported a segmentation fault or similar error." and if I add an implementation to the `FooImpl` or make the extension non-recursive, the sandbox would accept the code.

Comment: The sandbox only says that when you ask it to run the code.  At which time you try to perform an infinite recursion which causes a crash and leads to the error.  If you add an implementation to  `FooImpl` then you are no longer executing the default implementation that makes the infinitely recursive call that is causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You omitted a very important part of the implementation. *If* you do this you have to implement `foo` in `FooImpl`. If you do not implement it your code is basically equivalent to

```
protocol Foo {
}

extension Foo {
    func foo(_ a: Int = 4) {
        foo(a)
    }
}

struct FooImpl: Foo {
}

FooImpl().foo()
```

which obviously creates an infinite loop. If you correctly implement `foo` you will see the expected behaviour:

```
protocol Foo {
    func foo(_ a: Int)
}

extension Foo {
    func foo(_ a: Int = 4) {
        foo(a)
    }
}

struct FooImpl: Foo {
    func foo(_ a: Int) {
        print(a)
    }
}

FooImpl().foo()
```

Both are perfectly valid swift snippets, the only difference is that one actually works, the other will crash. But that is nothing the compiler is supposed to worry about.