# Can I create a constrained extension on Array so it only operates on [CGPoint]

Tags: arrays, swift, extension-methods

I am designing a function that will take an array of CGPoints, treat it as end points of a poly-line, and insert intermediate points using Catmull-Rom smoothing to create an approximation of a curve that passes through those points.

The function can be defined as a global function:

```
func smoothPoints(array: [CGPoint], granularity: Int = 4) -> [CGPoint] {
    return [CGPoint]() //Placeholder code for actual implementation
  }
```

But I'd like to be able to define it as a constrained extension on the `Array` type, so that it will only operate on arrays of `CGPoint`s. Is that possible?

The only examples of constrained extensions I've been able to find in Swift 3 constrain the array elements to objects that conform to a protocol, not a specific data (Struct) type.

It seems like I should be able to do something like this:

```
extension Array where Element: CGPoint {
func smoothPoints(granularity: Int = 4) -> [CGPoint] {
  }
}
```

But that gives me an error "type 'Element' constrained to non-protocol type 'CGPoint'".

The declaration

```
 extension Array<CGPoint>
```

...doesn't work either.

It seems like it should be possible to define an extension to the Array class that only operates on arrays of a specific type, but I can't figure out how to do so.

Is what I'm trying to do possible in Swift 3, or am I stuck with a global function?

Comment: Related: [Extend array types using where clause in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31806324/2976878), [How can I make a extension for array of specific type in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31842337/2976878). Simplest solution would be to extend `Collection` instead with the constraint `Iterator.Element == CGPoint`.

Comment: Although if your implementation relies on O(1) indexing, you should probably extend `RandomAccessCollection` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could constrain to a protocol that exposes the functionality you need and have CGPoint conform to it:

```
protocol Coordinates {
    var x: CGFloat { get }
    var y: CGFloat { get }
}

extension Array where Element: Coordinates {
    func smoothPoints(granularity: Int = 4) -> [Element] {
        return []  //Placeholder code for actual implementation
    }
}

extension CGPoint: Coordinates {}

let test: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)]
test.smoothPoints() // returns an Array<CGPoint>
```