# Extend swift array that hold specific element type

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I've been trying to extend a swift array that hold specific type.

```
protocol Node {
  var nodeId: Int { get }
  var parentId: Int? { get }
  var children: [Node]  { get set }
  var level: Int { get set }
}

extension Array where Element : Node {
/**
unflatten an array of Nodes.
*/
func unflattenNodes()-> [Node] {

    func unflatten(inout parent: Node?)-> [Node] {

        var topNodes = [Node]()
        let children = self.filter{ (child: Node) in return child.parentId == parent?.nodeId ?? 0 }

        if !children.isEmpty {

            if var parent = parent {
                for var child in children {
                    child.level = parent.level + 1
                }
                parent.children = children
            }
            else {
                topNodes = children
            }

            for child in children {
                var optChild = Optional(child)
                unflatten(&optChild)
            }
        }
        return topNodes;
    }

      var optChild: Node? = nil
      return unflatten(&optChild)
 }
}
```

This code above won't be compiled because 'Node' is not subtype of 'Element', even though I'm extending Array of element "Node". 
How can I archive what I'm trying to do here in swift?
I'm trying to add an instance method to [Node] to unflatten self.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806324/extend-array-types-using-where-clause-in-swift ?

Comment: I just tried and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the protocol `Node` doesn't conform to itself: `Node` is not of type `Node` (as contradicting as it sounds), because a protocol isn't a concrete type, it's just a requirement for the conforming type.

That said, you need to replace every instance of `Node` in your code with `Element`, then it should work (can't test it right now). This is because again, you're actually not handling some value of type `Node`, but rather a value of a type that conforms to `Node` (`Element` in your case)

Also you made a few other mistakes in your code, I'll leave that to someone else to correct as I'm out of time.

Answer (score 1):

Right, I've plugged the code into Playground and I found three issues. The first is the one mentioned by Kametrixom which is that you need to use `Element` as the type everywhere in `unflattenNodes`. When you have fixed that and got rid of all the `parent:` in the calls to `unflatten`, you'll be left with one error

```
parent.children = children
error: cannot assign a value of type '[Element]' to a value of type '[Node]'
                parent.children = children
                                  ^
```

This is caused by the fact that the `children` property in the protocol is defined as `[Node]` and Swift can't match it to an array of `Element`

So you need to change the protocol

```
protocol Node {
    var nodeId: Int { get }
    var parentId: Int? { get }
    var children: [Self]  { get set }
    //            ^^^^^^ Here
    var level: Int { get set }
}
```

The `children` property is no longer an array of `Node` but an array of whatever type is conforming to the protocol, in your case, `Element`

Answer (score 1):

Updating `extension Array where Element : Node` to `extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == Node` resolved the error.