# Swift 2D Array Extension

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make an Extension to the Array type so to be able to work with 2D arrays. In fact, I did this in Objective-C and the code below worked like a charm. But I really stuck in Swift.

```
extension Array {
    mutating func addObject(anObject : AnyObject, toSubarrayAtIndex idx : Int) {
        while self.count <= idx {
            let newSubArray = [AnyObject]()
            self.append(newSubArray)
        }

        var subArray = self[idx] as! [AnyObject]
        subArray.append(anObject)
    }

    func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath : NSIndexPath) -> AnyObject {
        let subArray = self[indexPath.section] as! Array
        return subArray[indexPath.row] as! AnyObject
    }
}
```

I get this error no matter what I do:

> Error: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '([AnyObject])'

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@brimstone's answer is close, but if I understand your question correctly, it is an array of `[AnyObject]`, which means it should look like this:

```
extension Array where Element: _ArrayType, Element.Generator.Element: AnyObject {
    mutating func addObject(anObject : Element.Generator.Element, toSubarrayAtIndex idx : Int) {
        while self.count <= idx {
            let newSubArray = Element()
            self.append(newSubArray) // ERROR: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '([AnyObject])'
        }

        var subArray = self[idx]
        subArray.append(anObject)
    }

    func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> AnyObject {
        let subArray = self[indexPath.indexAtPosition(0)]
        return subArray[indexPath.indexAtPosition(1)] as Element.Generator.Element
    }
}
```

Comment: You're brilliant! It worked but I really didn't get it all of that _ArrayType and Generator stuff. I have a lot to read I guess :)

Comment: In fact, there's an error I did make in the last two lines of the addObject method. The last line of the addObject method should look like this:   self[idx].append(anObject)

Comment: I guess I need help with Swift 3 :)

Comment: Ca you post how this would look like in Swift 3, because I don't seem to be able to translate it ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to say what the array element type is in the extension. Try this:

```
extension _ArrayType where Generator.Element == AnyObject {
    mutating func addObject(anObject: AnyObject, toSubarrayAtIndex idx: Int) {
        while self.count <= idx {
            let newSubArray = [AnyObject]()
            self.append(newSubArray)
        }

        var subArray = self[idx] as! [AnyObject]
        subArray.append(anObject)
    }

    func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> AnyObject {
        let subArray = self[indexPath.section] as! Array
        return subArray[indexPath.row] as! AnyObject
    }
}
```

From this question: [Extend array types using where clause in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806324/extend-array-types-using-where-clause-in-swift)