# 2D Array extension Swift 3.1.1

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, swift3

I am trying to make an `Array` extension in Swift 3.1.1 that supports the addition of an object to a certain index in a 2D Array **even if the array hasn't been populated yet**. The extension should also provide the ability to get an object at certain `indexPath`. I have the code for this in Swift 2 but I don't seem to be able to migrate it to Swift 3. This is the Swift 2 code:

```
extension Array where Element: _ArrayProtocol, Element.Iterator.Element: Any {

    mutating func addObject(_ anObject : Element.Iterator.Element, toSubarrayAtIndex idx : Int) {
        while self.count <= idx {
            let newSubArray = Element()
            self.append(newSubArray) 
        }

        var subArray = self[idx]
        subArray.append(anObject)
    }

    func objectAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Any {
        let subArray = self[indexPath.section]
        return subArray[indexPath.row] as Element.Iterator.Element
    }
}
```

The code is taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36212848/3844242).

Comment: Well first of all there is no `_ArrayProtocol` anymore in Swift3. I guess I don't need a `where` clause anymore? Not sure ..

Comment: Related: https://swift.org/migration-guide/ (maybe you know this already but if not, it will be of great help)

Comment: I am really not sure how to migrate the code to Swift 3. I tried by not using a `where` clause and instead of `Element.Iterator.Element` I simply use `Element` but then when I try to do `let newSubArray = Element()` I get `Element cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initiliaziers` I also tried making an extension of `Collection` instead of `Array` and use `Iterator.Element` instead of `Element` but with no success again.

Comment: I just can't get the syntax and everything right somehow ..

Comment: This seems important: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43338557/2227743

Comment: I've seen this already. However, that doesn't help me. As I said, when I get rid of the whole `where` clause there are other errors that I'm encountering.

Comment: Can you maybe just copy the code and try it on your machine? Then you would see what I mean, because it's hard for me to explain all problems that I encounter.

Comment: Can you post your best Swift 3 version (even if it doesn't compile yet)?

Comment: Unrelated, but note that the constraint `Element.Iterator.Element: Any` is thoroughly pointless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Martin says [in his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43338893/2976878), `_ArrayProtocol` [is no longer `public`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-3.1-branch/stdlib/public/core/ArrayType.swift#L13) in Swift 3.1, therefore meaning that you cannot use it as a constraint in your extension.

A simple alternative in your case is to instead constrain the `Array`'s `Element` to being a [`RangeReplaceableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/rangereplaceablecollection) – which both defines an `init()` requirement meaning "empty collection", and an `append(_:)` method in order to add elements to the collection.

```
extension Array where Element : RangeReplaceableCollection {

    typealias InnerCollection = Element
    typealias InnerElement = InnerCollection.Iterator.Element

    mutating func fillingAppend(
        _ newElement: InnerElement,
        toSubCollectionAtIndex index: Index) {

        if index >= count {
            append(contentsOf: repeatElement(InnerCollection(), count: index + 1 - count))
        }

        self[index].append(newElement)
    }
}
```

Note also that we're doing the append as a single call (using `append(contentsOf:`), ensuring that we only have to resize the outer array at most once.

For your method to get an element from a given `IndexPath`, you can just constrain the inner element type to being a [`Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection) with an `Int` `Index`:

```
// could also make this an extension on Collection where the outer Index is also an Int.
extension Array where Element : Collection, Element.Index == Int {

    subscript(indexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> Element.Iterator.Element {
        return self[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Note that I've made it a `subscript` rather than a method, as I feel it fits better with `Array`'s API.

You can now simply use these extensions like so:

```
var arr = [[Int]]()

arr.fillingAppend(6, toSubCollectionAtIndex: 3)
print(arr) // [[], [], [], [6]]

let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 3)
print(arr[indexPath: indexPath]) // 6
```

Although of course if you know the size of the outer array in advance, the `fillingAppend(_:toSubCollectionAtIndex:)` method is redundant, as you can just create your nested array by saying:

```
var arr = [[Int]](repeating: [], count: 5)
```

which will create an `[[Int]]` array containing 5 empty `[Int]` elements.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! The code worked as a charm and was exactly what I was looking for! Well written and documented answer, learned a lot from it!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to limit all these ideas to the concrete `Array` type.

Here's my solution. This discussion was great in that I just learned about `RangeReplaceableCollection`. Merging (what I think is) the best of both worlds, I pushed all the operations down (up?) the Type hierarchy as far as possible.

Subscript works on much more than `Array` as @Hamish says. But also, there's no need to constrain the index type, so we have to get rid of `IndexPath`. We can always sugar this with `typealias Index2d = ...`

```
extension Collection where Self.Element: Collection {
    subscript(_ indexTuple: (row: Self.Index, column: Self.Element.Index)) -> Self.Element.Element {
        get {
            return self[indexTuple.row][indexTuple.column]
        }
    }
}
```

Why not have a mutable version at the most generic possible level (between `Collection` and `RangeReplaceableCollection`) (unfortunately I don't think the getter can be inherited when we redefine `subscript`):

```
extension MutableCollection where Self.Element: MutableCollection {
    subscript(_ indexTuple: (row: Self.Index, column: Self.Element.Index)) -> Self.Element.Element {
        get {
            return self[indexTuple.row][indexTuple.column]
        }
        set {
            self[indexTuple.row][indexTuple.column] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if you want to initialize lazily, avoid using `init:repeatedValue` and revise `set` to have auto-initialization semantics.  You can trap bounds overflow and add missing empty elements in both dimensions by integrating the accepted answer's `fillingAppend` idea.

And when creating a 2D initializer, why not extend the idea of `repeating` in the natural way:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    init(repeating repeatedVal: Element.Element, extents: (row: Int, column: Int)) {
        let repeatingColumn = Element(repeating: repeatedVal, count: extents.column)
        self.init(repeating: repeatingColumn, count: extents.row)
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
enum Player {
    case first
    case second
}

class Model {
    let playerGrid: Array<Array<Player>> = {
        var p = [[Player]](repeating: .first, extents: (row: 10, column: 10))
        p[(3, 4)] = .second
        print("Player at 3, 4 is: \(p[(row: 3, column: 4)])")
        return p
    }()
}
```