# Extending typed Arrays (of primitive types like Bool) in Swift 3?

Tags: arrays, swift, extension-methods, swift3

Previously in Swift 2.2 I'm able to do:

```
extension _ArrayType where Generator.Element == Bool{
    var allTrue : Bool{
        return !self.contains(false)
    }
}
```

which extends `[Bool]` with `.allTrue`. E.g.

```
[true, true, false].allTrue == false
```

But in Swift 3.0 I'm getting this error:

> undeclared type `_ArrayType`

---

So I tried switching it to `Array` and using the new keyword `Iterator`

```
extension Array where Iterator.Element == Bool
    var allTrue : Bool{
        return !self.contains(false)
    }
}
```

But I got a different error complaining that I'm forcing element to be non-generic

> Same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Element' non-generic

---

I've also tried the solutions in this [2 years old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027116/how-can-i-extend-typed-arrays-in-swift) but to no avail.

So how does one extend arrays of primitive types like Bool in Swift 3?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806324/extend-array-types-using-where-clause-in-swift

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just extend the Collection or the Sequence

```
extension Collection where Element == Bool { 
    var allTrue: Bool { return !contains(false) }
}
```

---

edit/update:

**Xcode 10 • Swift 4 or later**

You can use Swift 4 or later collection method [allSatisfy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994715-allsatisfy)

```
let alltrue = [true, true,true, true,true, true].allSatisfy{$0}  // true

let allfalse = [false, false,false, false,false, false].allSatisfy{!$0} // true
```

---

```
extension Collection where Element == Bool {
    var allTrue: Bool { return allSatisfy{ $0 } }
    var allFalse: Bool { return allSatisfy{ !$0 } }
}
```

---

Testing Playground:

```
[true, true, true, true, true, true].allTrue // true
[false, false, false, false, false, false].allFalse // true
```

Answer (score 8):

Apple replaced `_ArrayType` with `_ArrayProtocol` in Swift 3.0 ([see Apple's Swift source code on GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ArrayType.swift)) so you can do the same thing you did in Swift 2.2 by doing the following:

```
extension _ArrayProtocol where Iterator.Element == Bool {
    var allTrue : Bool { return !self.contains(false) }
}
```

Comment: This is almost correct, If you extend _ArrayProtocol you would need to constraint it  `where Iterator.Element == Bool`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Very interesting. I almost forgot it was open-sourced.

Comment: No problem, I was having a similar issue (in addition to several others) migrating from Swift 2 to 3 and figured looking through the source code couldn't hurt. @LeoDabus any chance you could explain why you need to constrain `_ArrayProtocol` with `where Iterator.Element == Bool` as opposed to just `where Element == Bool`?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `Use of undeclared type _ArrayProtocol`

Comment: Yes. Extending the Collection didn't work either but extending the Sequence did.

Answer (score 1):

As of Swift 3.1 (included in Xcode 8.3), you can now [extend a type with a concrete constraint](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift3-1):

```
extension Array where Element == Bool {
    var allTrue: Bool {
        return !contains(false)
    }
}
```

You can also extend `Collection` instead of `Array`, but you'll need to constrain `Iterator.Element`, not just `Element`.

Comment: You could generalize it even further, to an extension on `Sequence`

Answer (score 0):

Extending `_ArrayProtocol` or `Collection` didn't work for me but `Sequence` did.

```
public extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == String
{
    var allTrue: Bool { return !contains(false)
}
```