# where did _ArrayType go in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift-protocols

I have some code that used to relay on `_ArrayType` in pre Swift 3. I am trying to understand what happened to public protocol `_ArrayType`.

Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628695/extending-typed-arrays-of-primitive-types-like-bool-in-swift-3.

Comment: What were you using `_ArrayType` for? Undocumented changes like this one is exactly why you should try to avoid underscored protocols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_ArrayType` was renamed `_ArrayProtocol`.  You can see this in the [ArrayType.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ArrayType.swift) file and [this commit](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/db84df9eabbc5902dbe6798e31237946d75533a5).

```
internal protocol _ArrayProtocol
  : RangeReplaceableCollection,
    ExpressibleByArrayLiteral
{
    // ...
}
```